# How to derive a condition for a characteristic surface of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, characteristics

Consider the wave equation in two spatial dimensions

$$\tag{1}
\partial_{tt}u-c^2(\partial_{xx}u+\partial_{yy}u)=0
$$

I want to show that an *implicit surface* $\phi(x,y,t)=0$ is a characteristic surface of (1) if

$$\tag{2}
(\partial_t\phi)^2-c^2\left[(\partial_x\phi)^2+(\partial_y\phi)^2\right]=0
$$

**Question: How to derive (2)?**

Details: We suppose that Cauchy data: $u\big|_\phi$ (the value of $u$ everywhere on $\phi$) and $\partial_\phi u \big|_\phi$ (the normal derivative of $u$ to $\phi$) have been supplied on the surface $\phi$. We will call $\phi$ a characteristic surface if the quantity $\partial_{\phi \phi} u \big|_\phi$ cannot be computed from the Cauchy data and the differential equation (1).

**Context:** The example, as well as (2) is from [these notes](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Etabak/PDEs/Characteristic%20lines%20and%20surfaces.pdf) section 8.3.

**What I think:** I understand the simpler example (section 8.2) for a PDE of two variables

$$
a \partial_{xx}u+b\partial_{xy}u+c\partial_{yy}u=d
$$

with an initial condition; $u$ and the normal derivative of $u$, given along the *parametric curve* $(x(s),y(s))$. In this case one forms a system of equations for the unknowns $\partial_{xx}u, \ \partial_{xy}u, \ \partial_{yy}u$, which fails to have a unique solution if

$$\tag{3}
ay'(s)^2-2bx'(s)y'(s)+cx'(s)^2=0
$$

It is not obvious to me how an analogous argument will yield (2).

Comment: Can you flesh out what you mean by "characteristic surface"?

Comment: I think the third derivative is about "y" in equation (1). Without knowing your background, a glimpse at chapter 3 of "wave propagation in elastic media" written by Achenbach will help you. Also, I think your question is technically not clear.

Comment: @ALIN Thanks, I corrected the typo in (2). What was unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the change of co-ordinates from $x,y,t$ to $\phi,r,s$. We want to rewrite (1) in the new co-ordinates. When we do, we will find; schematically,

$$\tag{1b}
F \ \partial_{\phi\phi}u+\text{lower/other derivatives}=0
$$

Where $F=F(\partial_x\phi,\partial_y\phi,\partial_t\phi)$. The surfaces $\phi(x,y,t)=\text{constant}$ will be characteristic surfaces if $F=0$ so that $\partial_{\phi\phi}u$ cannot be obtained from (1b). Using the chain rule and picking out only the coefficients of $\partial_{\phi\phi}u$ we find directly that $F=\text{LHS of (2)}$.